# Checking for null avoiding null?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm a bit confused here (undoubtedly due to being new to C# and entity framework but that's besides the point) I want to check for a situation where my query to the database returns no data and upon that happening set some values to variables on my page Below is the code I have up right now which is throwing an error telling me that I need to check for null on the very line where I am checking for null (if the UserName value is null the record was not returned as it is a required column). So what am I missing on how to go about checking for null return here?

```
using (CInTracDBEntities Context = new CInTracDBEntities())
{
var CInTracUsers = Context.CInTracUsers.Where(a => a.Login == HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name).Select(x => new { x.Login, x.UserName, x.Status, x.StatusDate, x.ReviewDate }).FirstOrDefault();
if (CInTracUsers.UserName == null)
```

Thanks,
Ken....

Comment: Your `CInTracUsers.UserName == null` check will check to see if `UserName` is null, the problem you are having is that `CInTracUsers` is the thing that is null. Read the linked duplicate to learn the debugging skills on how to solve the problem.

Comment: Is it actually throwing an error, or is your IDE simply trying to tell you that `CInTracUsers` _may_ be null, which it will be if your `Where` fails to match anything.

Comment: `null`-ness isn't transitive.  `CInTracUsers` is `null`, so attempting to access it's `UserName` property is an exception.

Comment: change if `(CInTracUsers.UserName == null)` to `if (CInTracUsers != null && CInTracUsers.UserName == null)`

Comment: You are correct. I just realized that I misread the question about which line the error was on.

Comment: @bto.rdz I think you hit the nail on the head but further in my code I'm having similar issues when I go to assign return values to session variables. example: Session["CITLogin"] = CInTracUsers.Login; 
also wants me to check for null after going though the check on the return record earlier. 
Maybe I should start a new thread just for that..Whadya think?
Ken...

Comment: Would have to write each one something like this? 
     if (CInTracUsers != null && CInTracUsers.Login != null)
                    {
                        Session["CITLogin"] = CInTracUsers.Login;
                    }

Answer (score 0):

ask for the whole object:

```
if (CInTracUsers == null)
```

because if `CInTracUsers` is null you'll get an exception when calling any of his proprties

Comment: If using the latest C# version, he could also use `if(CInTracUsers?.UserName == null) `